# Getting Error Invalid user of matcher Exception

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have method to to test junit below

```
public Response submitData(String a, BigInteger b, HttpServletRequest request){
}
```

I have mockito junit method below

```
@Test
public void submitData_Success() throws Exception {
    when(inAbcExample.submitData(anyString(),eq(new BigInteger("12")),mockRequest)).thenReturn(response);
}
```

I'm getting invalid use of matcher exception. whether above lines are correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is present when you try to pass some params using the `anyXXX()` mockito wrappers and yet some of you params are still passed normally (like the`mockRequest` in your case). You should refactor to the following:

```
@Test
public void submitData_Success() throws Exception {
    when(inAbcExample.submitData(anyString()
           ,Mockito.eq(new BigInteger("12")),Mockito.eq(mockRequest))).thenReturn(response);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Maciej Kowalski, Its worked for me

Comment: Great. Glad i could help